# Facing 503 Error message on AWS Instance after migrating to newer Instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I am trying to migrate my AWS Linux 1 env to AWS Linux 2.
So in parallel I configured AWS Linux 2  and my project is deployed correctly there.
My issue is when I try to switch the DNS entry to point to my new environment. I am swapping url for it, but my requests to the new env I receive:
Status: 503 Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity
Source: Network

Maybe I am missing any step?
Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely to misconfigure your health-check, which could returns an error because your (proxy-) server is not working correctly). Check your ELB logs.
Try grepping the log files folder using the "ELB-HealthChecker" user agent. e.g. grep ELB-HealthChecker  /var/log/httpd/*